# Emacs -nw color-theme and terminal transparency

Tags: terminal, emacs, themes, gnome-terminal, solarized

I'm using `M-x load-theme` to load `color-theme-solorized` from the marmalade repository and it works and gets the color correct. The problem I'm having is that if I run `emacs -nw` in `gnome-terminal` that has transparency, the transparency gets lost.
Is there any way to have this color theme and keep terminal transparency?
I'd also like to point out that I have set `export TERM=xterm-256color` in my .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, a workaround for this is to apply following changes to solarized-definitions.el:

Find this Code:
(base03      (find-color 'base03))

Replace it with:
(base03      ())

Make sure to recompile it, if you don't the "old" binary version in solarized-definitions.elc is used, regardless of your changes in solarized-definitions.el